# Prestashop 1.6 payment module order state

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created payment module for Prestashop 1.6.1.1.

The problem is with updating order state after customer returns from banks website. I can not get cart from context as shown on examples.

For example, this is controller, which is executed, when customer presses cancel button on bank:

```
class MyModulePaymentCancelModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController{
    public function initContent(){
        $cart = $this->context->cart;
    }
}
```

The cart value is null. It seems like the cart has been deleted / discarded prior to the controller.

In the contrary, I get proper cart from context in MyModule**Payment**ModuleFrontController (creating order) and MyModulePayment**Return**ModuleFrontController (payment completed successfully).

Could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cart is destroyed as soon as order is created. I sent order id to the bank, which I expected to be returned and then used that as reference point for updating orders.

Comment: correct, when order is created you do not have access to cart object.
there are some methods that can help you if you need access to cart features  `Order::getCartIdStatic($id_order)`, `$order->getCartProducts()` same as `$order->getProducts()` just in cart "view".